# Format a string using sprintf in c

Tags: c, printf

I am using sprintf for string formation in C.

I need to insert '+' and '-' sign before float value.

This positive and negative signs are inserted by checking a flag after that i insert the float value.

Now i want to make this whole number in right alignment along with positive or negative sign.

Currently this is my formatted string:

```
+300.00
-200.00
+34.60
```

I want output like following,

```
+300.00
+233.45
 -20.34
```

I have written following code:

```
char printbuff[1000], flag = 1;
double temp=23.34, temp1= 340.45;   

sprintf(printBuff, "%c%-lf\n%c%-lf",
        (Flag == 1) ? '+' : '-',
        temp,
        (Flag == 1) ? '+'  :'-',
        temp1);
```

I am getting following output:

```
+23.34
+340.45
```

Instead of the desired:

```
 +23.45
+340.45
```

How can I do this?

Comment: [Whathaveyoutried.com](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: You've tagged two languages: do you want a C answer, or a C++ one?

Comment: DarkCthulhu : No %-nf is not working.

Answer (score 2):

use like this

```
sprintf(outputstr, "%+7.2f", double_number);
```

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void output_string(char output_buffer[], double nums[], size_t size){
/*  use '+' flag version
    int i,len=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;++i)
        len += sprintf(output_buffer + len, "%+7.2f\n", nums[i]);
*/  //handmade version
    int i, len=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
        char sign = nums[i] < 0 ? '-' : '+';
        char *signp;
        double temp = abs(nums[i]);

        len += sprintf(signp = output_buffer + len, "%7.2f\n", temp);
        signp[strcspn(signp, "0123456789")-1] = sign;//The width including the sign is secured
    }
}

int main(){
    double nums[] = {
        +300.00,
        -200.00,
         +34.60,
        +300.00,
        +233.45,
         -20.34
    };
    char output_buffer[1024];
    int size = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(*nums);

    output_string(output_buffer, nums, size);
    printf("%s", output_buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have seen the space BEFORE the sign?

Comment: @PeterMiehle It is right-justified without specifying when width is secured sufficiently large.

Comment: his signdness is not coded into the float value, but flagged.

Comment: @PeterMiehle don't need his `flag (Flag)`.

Comment: his number IS Always positive! The flag says the signdness

Comment: @PeterMiehle It will those obtained from the numerical value of the original?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```
char str[1000];
double v = 3.1415926;
sprintf(str, "%+6.2f", v);
```

The + indicates "show sign".

A more complete bit of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double a[] = { 0, 3.1415, 333.7, -312.2, 87.8712121, -1000.0 };
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
    {
        printf("%+8.2f\n", a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
   +0.00
   +3.14
 +333.70
 -312.20
  +87.87
-1000.00
```

Obviously, using sprintf, there would be a buffer involved, but I believe this shows the solution more easily.

Comment: I'm curious as to why this was down-voted... Is it something about "standard doesn't support + and - at the same time - it certainly works with glibc.

Comment: '-' flag is left-justified.

Comment: Gah! Can you tell it's been a while since I used printf?

Comment: I have no idea why this was downvoted, but I've added a piece of code that shows how this works.

Comment: I am inserting + or - sign.

Comment: So, you are not printing a positive or negative number, but wanting to print a + or - infront of an already positive number? And you want to format that to a certain width, with the number tight to the + or - ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
char s[100];
double x=-100.00;

sprintf(s,"%s%f",x<0?"":"+",x);
printf("\n%s",s);
x = 1000.01;
sprintf(s,"%s%f",x<0?"":"+",x);
printf("\n%s",s);
return 0;
}
```

Here is the code.
Its O/p is ::

```
-100.000000
+1000.010000
```

Comment: @AnishRam Why negative comment...He asked this so i provided the solution

Comment: Because spoonfeeding isn't going to help the OP. Why don't you just provide hints to the solution instead? Clearly the OP has put in very little effort into solving this problem.

Comment: For `x = -0.0`, you will get `"+-0.000000"`, and for `x = 0.0/-0.0`, you can get `"+-nan"`. The simple `x < 0` check fails on edge-cases.

Answer (score 0):

you need a separate buffer, in which you sprintf your number with your sign, and that resulting string you can sprintf into the rightjustified resultbuffer.